# Javascript Set/WeakSet datastructures with objects/arrays

Tags: javascript, set

I'm using a random generator to create a pair of numbers and need to figure out if a number pair has occured earlier. I thought of using Set() but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var a = [1, 2]
var s = new Set();
s.add(a) //Set {[1, 2]}
s.add([1, 2]) //Set {[1, 2], [1, 2]}
```

I suspect this is because JS stores reference as opposed to value. Is there any way that it would only store that array/pair once and returns TRUE based on value?

Comment: You answered your own question. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set "The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references." The two arrays are unique references. If you tried `s.add(a);` again, it would not re-add the array.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript checks for equality with `===`. The downside is that comparing objects/arrays/functions is usually not as straightforward.

If the format is consistent, you can use a bit of an ugly hack: `JSON.stringify()` your arrays, and add the strings to the Set. The strings will be considered equal, unlike the arrays which have different references.